# String Grid and Graphic in cells

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have put icons in the string grid but I ran into a problem with not all the graphics are aligned. I have tried to rework the centering the text to make the icons align but no luck. I have tried to research the bitmap and its functionality but I havent (so I think) found anything that will help me. Can anyone help me please?

EDIT (from code added in answer to question by mistake):

```
bitmap := Tbitmap.Create;
bitmap.LoadFromFile('equal.bmp');
bitmap.SetSize(150,60);
stringgrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(stringgrid1.CellRect(3,J), bitmap);
SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, TA_CENTER);
StringGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(stringgrid1.CellRect(3,J),
   (stringgrid1.CellRect(3,J).Left+stringgrid1.CellRect(3,J).Right) div 2,

stringgrid1.CellRect(3,J).Top + 5,StringGrid1.Cells[3,J]);
SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, TA_LEFT);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit your question to add the code you have so far for the TStringGrid.OnDrawCell event handler and a screen capture of what the result is you're getting now, so we can see what the problem is you're trying to solve? It will make it much easier to give you a better answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Moved code from answer below into this one. If that's your actual code, it's very wrong, and appears to be from somewhere other than the OnDrawCell event handler. In addition, please edit your post and add a screen capture of what your code currently does, since we don't have your `equal.bmp` or know anything about your grid's layout. (You can edit if you log in using the same ID you used to post the original question; you should edit to clarify or add new information rather than posting an answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example (Delphi 7, since it's what I had handy, but the code should work in D2010):

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Bmp:  TBitmap;
  CellText: string;
  R: TRect;
const
  L_PAD = 5;  // Amount between right side of image and start of text
  T_PAD = 5;   // Amount between top of cell and top of text
begin
  // Some text to display in cells.
  CellText := Format('Row: %d Col: %d', [ARow, ACol]);

  // Draw an image along the left side of each cell in the first
  // col (not the fixed ones, which we'll leave alone)
  if ((ACol = 1) or (ACol = 3)) and  (ARow > 0) then
  begin
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.LoadFromFile('C:\glyfx\common\bmp\24x24\favorites24.bmp');
      if ACol = 1 then // left align image
      begin
        R.Top := Rect.Top + 1;
        R.Left := Rect.Left + 1;
        R.Right := R.Left + Bmp.Width;
        R.Bottom := R.Top + Bmp.Height;
        StringGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, Bmp);
        StringGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(R.Right + L_PAD, R.Top + T_PAD, CellText);
      end
      else
      begin // right align image
        StringGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + L_PAD,
                                   Rect.Top + L_PAD,
                                   CellText);
        R.Top := Rect.Top + 1;
        R.Left := Rect.Right - Bmp.Width - 1;
        R.Right := Rect.Right - 1;
        R.Bottom := R.Top + L_PAD + Bmp.Height;
        StringGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, Bmp);
      end;
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    StringGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + L_PAD, Rect.Top + T_PAD, CellText);
end;
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: StringGrid with image aligned]